# Why does this Python (using 3.7) renamer not allow directories to start with a number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rename

I have created the following renamer (below) to replace periods from the filename and directory name, which seems to work fine for filenames but doesn't work for directory names if they start with an integer. No errors are raised. If there are no integers in any directory names, then it works fine for directories. Otherwise, it simply renames the files but not the directories. Can anybody tell me why and how to get around this?

Any help is much appreciated.

```
import os

def Replace_Filename(Root_Folder):

    for Root, Dirs, Files in os.walk(Root_Folder):
       for File in Files:
        print(File)
        Fname, Fext = os.path.splitext(File)
        print(Fname)
        print(Fext)
        Replaced = Fname.replace(".","_")
        print(Replaced)
        New_Fname = Replaced + Fext
        print(New_Fname)
        F_path = os.path.join(Root, File)
        print(F_path)
        New_Fpath = os.path.join(Root, New_Fname)
        print(New_Fpath)
        os.rename(F_path, New_Fpath)


def Replace_Dirname(Root_Folder):

    for Root, Dirs, Files in os.walk(Root_Folder):
       for Dir in Dirs:
        print(Dir)
        New_Dname = Dir.replace(".","_")
        print(New_Dname)
        D_Path = os.path.join(Root, Dir)
        print(D_Path)
        New_Dpath = os.path.join(Root, New_Dname)
        print(New_Dpath)
        os.rename(D_Path, New_Dpath)




Root_Folder = "D:\\Practicerename-Copy"
Replace_Filename(Root_Folder)
Replace_Dirname(Root_Folder)
```

Comment: What do "does not allow" and "doesn't work" mean? Are you getting errors? Are such directories skipped?

Comment: The filenames get changed fine but no directory names are changed. No errors occur.

Comment: If there are no integers at the start of the directory names then it works fine for both filenames and directory names. If there are integers on any of the directory names then it renames the files but not the directories and doesn't give any errors.

Comment: your code works well for me, python3.7 win10. Do you have any additional notes that could help to understand the issue?

Comment: Thanks for testing. I really can't think of anything. I wondered whether it might be something to do with needing to read the dir names as string literals but the numbers interfere?

Comment: maybe its a stupid idea but could you provide with name of folders, maybe you have some regularity in names.

Comment: For example: 12.12.19_NEAA. If this and other files like it are present, no files get changed. However: Fed_12.12.19_NEAA, changes with no issues. Really baffled by this.